# Miscalculation of grace period?

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

I think there is a small bug. Please look at the picture below. Since bounty period ended 23 hours ago, its grace period should not be ended yet. But it says it did.

[image]

Comment: Why would you not only not link to [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595956/android-how-to-get-a-video-thumbnail-of-a-file-thats-private-to-your-applicati), but blank out completely public information?

Comment: It still shows on the "active" sub-tab of his Bounties tab.  Interesting.

Comment: @MatthewRead Well, it must still be active if the box is showing up on the post. It looks like it should end at 21:50Z

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Sorry, it was dumb. Hiding identity must've become my habit.

Comment: I assume the "auto awarding" is done via a job, e.g. running every hour over all ended bounties granting to highest voted answer etc. So I would wait until 22:50Z (40 minutes from now) before starting to worry.

Comment: Hmm.. still nothing. Guess it's a bug then!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, this is a bug, and it has nothing to do with when the hourly job runs.

[image: bounty was added at 16:25]

[image: grace period expired at 15:25]

As you can see, the bounty was added at 16:25, but the grace period expired at 15:25.

I haven't been awarded the bounty yet and I don't know when it will happen, but the grace period either hasn't ended yet or it was only *23* hours long.

Comment: If feel you're right, and not meaning to be nit picking: why do you say the grace period ended 15:25? To be super precise, shouldn't that read: *it ended somewhere before 15:38*? Or do you have some other info too? (As an aside: you can also hover the "23 hours" [to see the bounty times](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qev8m.png).)

Comment: Ah, [Won't's profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/wont?tab=bounties) still lists it [as being in the grace period](http://i.stack.imgur.com/C4NZ2.png).

Comment: I have checked the page at 15:27 or something, so I'm pretty sure the grace period timer just has a rounding bug.

Comment: Bounty got auto-awarded at 17:35.

Comment: I guess we'll never know if Won't could actually still award it manually during the last hour. I've one expiring in three days; maybe I am around to test then... The bug shouldn't be too hard to find though, I guess.

Comment: There was another bug here with display only (not the awarding) which used `.TotalHours` on a `TimeSpan` that messed up the display on the last hour...it's been re-written for the next build and will now display correctly.

Answer (score 4):

The bounty auto-award job does indeed run once an hour, there may be a gap between when the bounty ends and when *that* runs that you'll see an oddity like this, it's normal.

Comment: There was that, but the bug he actually reported is that the grace period ended less that 24 hours after the bounty did. That seems wrong and unrelated to the hourly job

Comment: I don't think this is by design. I took a few screenshots to support my claim. Please take a look at my answer.