# Why wasn't the bounty awarded on this question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties

Can someone help explain how bounties should work in this situation:

[Automatically build resource class based of XML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737344/automatically-build-resource-class-based-of-xml-in-java)

The asker didn't award the bounty, but the answer met the criteria for automatic 50% bounty before the grace period. Reading the FAQ, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be awarded.

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate, but I now realize that the actual question asked isn't the same, even if it was answered as though it were.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nick Craver explains this in [Miscalculation of grace period?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118070/134300):

> The bounty auto-award job does indeed run once an hour, there may be a gap between when the bounty ends and when *that* runs that you'll see an oddity like this, it's normal.

Comment: Yes indeed, patience is a virtue: I just received the full amount. I re-read the bounty FAQ: while the delay isn't mentioned, I now realise that due to the answer being accepted the full bounty would be awarded in any case, but only at the time of expiration. Thanks!