# Why the automatic bounty are not awarded is not clear some times?

Tags: discussion, bounties, expired-bounty

The [FAQ on bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty):

```
1. The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum
    duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace
    period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty.

 2. If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace
    period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started
    with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If
    there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded
    to anyone.
```

**Taken together** just want to ask simple question why the bounty are not awarded automatically is not clear some times.

Eg. [web kit scrollbar not chaging until i hover over it when changing themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323552/web-kit-scrollbar-not-chaging-until-i-hover-over-it-when-changing-themes/12457954#12457954)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Wait for some time. Give some time to run scripts.** Bounties will be awarded to you. It takes time to run automatic scripts. Usually it takes 1-2 hours after grace period for automatic awarded bounty.

Nick Craver explains this in [Miscalculation of grace period?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118070/134300):

> The bounty auto-award job does indeed run once an hour, there may be a gap between when the bounty ends and when *that* runs that you'll see an oddity like this, it's normal.

Comment: but what if someone get more eligible to the bounty in that case bounty will be awarded to which user?

Comment: I am not sure but it might be checking current status of votes. But script will be making decision. High rep user or moderators can answer about this question.

Comment: @Champ `If two or more eligible answers have the same score, the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.`

Comment: yes i know that. but in my example there is not the case you specify

Comment: This explanation needs to be added to the FAQ. I was getting nervous and almost asked a question "soon-to-be-closed" here because I was not receiving the bounty (still not as of writing this).

Answer (score 1):

From [FAQ on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/187824):

> **What is automatic awarding?**
>
> Twenty-four hours after the end of the bounty period, if the bounty
> starter has not manually awarded the bounty, an eligible answer can be
> automatically awarded half the bounty amount.
>
> If two or more eligible answers have the same score, the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.

So Twenty-four hours after the end of the bounty period, an eligible answer can be automatically awarded *half* the bounty amount

Comment: But the Twenty-four hours period (grace period) has also ended

Comment: As @Somnath Muluk said: `Wait for sometime. Give sometime to run scripts.`